# Using arguments in bash from C command line

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell

Is it even possible to transfer command line arguments with execl from C to bash? cuz with C to C file i was getting exect formatt error. so decided to try C main, and bash son script, everything is running fine, except that i can't figure out how to transfer that argv with execl and than use it with son..

**FATHER**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pid;

    if (argc==4)
    {
        printf ("Need to enter 3 arguments");
        printf ("\tOne Process yet, creating second...\n");
        pid = fork();
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Need to give me 3 arguments\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    }
    if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("\tChild process launched...\n");
        execl("./testB", "testB", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], NULL);
        perror("execl dissapointed us");
    }
    else if(pid>0)
    {
        printf ("\twaiting for my child to finish...\n");
        wait((int *)0);
        printf("\t Child finished, time for father...\n");
        printf("Main Father\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("We've got an error, boss\n");
    }
    printf("Two proccesses?\n");
    printf("Number of arguments %d", argc);
}
```

**SON**

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "im da testB\n"
echo "Iveskite norima kieki konvertacijai"
read litai
while [ "$litai" -le 0 ]
do
echo "Iveskite norima kieki konvertacijai"
read litai
done
SUM=$( echo "scale=4;$litai*3.4528" | bc )  
printf "Jusu pasirinktas litu kiekis %d atitinka %s eurus\n" "$litai"    "$SUM"
printf "asd %s\n" "$argv[1]"
```

Comment: `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Aren't you already calling the script with the three first arguments to the C program?

Comment: Yes, but i want these arguments to give it to the son . that Father and Bash son would have these same arguments, and than use it from son. Idk if it's even the best way to use execl than, but i want them both to have that father arguments and than son be able to use them.

Comment: But that's exactly what the code is doing. What do you expect to happend and  does not work as you expect?

Comment: i think this "execl("./testB", "testB", argv[1], argv[2], argv[3], NULL);" not really works, cuz i tried many variatons on son how to use them.. like the last line of son, or if functions and so on.. and none of them works, so that means, son cant see and cant use that argv1, 2, 3.. and i want him to be able to see them and use them. IF thats even possible

Comment: OT and nit-picking: The last parameter passed to `execl()` shall be `(char*) NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
printf "asd %s\n" "$argv[1]"
```

to be

```
printf "asd %s\n" "$1"
```

to print the 1<sup>st</sup> argument passed to `testB`.

In `bash` arguments to the script are referred to by using `$n` with `n` starting with `1`.

---

Also: The last parameter passed to [`execl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) shall be `(char*) NULL`.

From [`man exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html):

> The list of
>          arguments must be terminated by a null pointer, and, since these are
>          variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Comment: In C you should not explicitly typecast `void*` pointers to any other pointer type. So the advice to pass `(char*)NULL` is, well, not wrong, but bad style. In fact, it's perfectly valid to just pass a `0` there as well (the number literal `0` always converts to the null pointer if a pointer type is expected).

Comment: @datenwolf: Although in general I am with you. This case is different. `execl()` is a variadic function. To make sure it pulls the right number of bytes to successfully detect the `NULL` being passed, the calling code needs to make sure the right type is passed. Also please see my updated answer.

Comment: Oops, totally missed that. Still, just passing NULL as defined as `(void*)0` would have been sufficient, since `void*` is asserted to be large enough to hold pointers to any regular object (not function pointers though).

Comment: `char *` is not guaranteed to be big enough to hold a `void *`, though.